# Select a category from a dropdown list -> print the subcategories of that category in a different list

Tags: php

I have 2 dropdown lists. In the first i have Parent Categories with Car Brands ( Seat,Audi etc). Each Category for example Seat has many subCategories that are the diffent models : Seat Cordoba,Seat Leon etc.

What i cant find out is, how i actually can pass the id of the Category selected in list 1 to server side so i Can make the query to db and parse the children of first category.

To be as clear as i can, Here is a more detailed example with picture from what im trying to do :

[image]

After the user selects "Audi" , need to get the value from the `<option>` and pass it somehow again at server-side to send a new query to the database,so i can create the second list also,with the models from Audi.

Is this even doable at all,to make the client-side communicate with server-side?
Or i need to find out a completly different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this tutorial. It will help you solve your problem. It's Ajax + Php + MySQL

[PHP Ajax and MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You will require to pass the value of category drop down list.

For the same you have to use Ajax and call a php file/script which will populate the sub category according to the value received from the category drop down list.

Ajax is required for it.